# HDLC frame HCS and FCS

Tags: hdl-coder

I have an HDLC frame like blow and I want to calculate the HCS and FCS algorithm.
Its based on DLMS protocol noted in green book page 128.

Here is an example of this frame:

Ex.1:

```
Frame=`(7EA016030002002352A25EE6E700C401C10012000211927E)Hex`
HCS = `( 52A2 )Hex`
Data= `( 5EE6E700C401C100120002 )Hex`
FCS = `( 1192 )Hex`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FCS can be computed using the method in 8.5.3 and the lookup can be generated using the method in 8.5.4 of the Green Book 8.3.
HCS is calculated in the same way.